# Delay loading of stylesheet in old browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, onload, delayed-execution

In a (Wordpress) website's `<head>`, I have the following code to load an additional stylesheet *after* all dynamic html and inline CSS created by a (third-party) slider plugin has been created via JS:

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/slider-styles1.css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

The reason for the necessity to load that additional stylesheet *later* than the main stylesheet is that it contains some `calc` values for `height` settings which depend on other calculated (inline css) values created by the plugin which again depend on the the size of images loaded by the plugin. A rather complex thing, there was actually some trial and error involved before I got it working, since I don't know *what* the plugin actually does in *which*  order.

---

**My problem**: This works in all current browsers, but in some older browsers (for example Firefox < 55, reported by a user with a very old computer) the related stylesheet is not loaded at all. Apparently (also according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=preload)) older browsers don't know `<link rel="preload">`.

So **my question** is if there is anything I can replace that line of code with, which also would work in older browsers?

Comment: `rel="preload"` is to start downloading a resource sooner in the page load lifecycle as an optimization; the stylesheet wouldn't actually be _used_ unless you had a `<link rel="stylesheet">` referencing that same URL. You shouldn't need preload since you're always just loading it after the fact.

Comment: Why would you support a user who refuses to update a free browser? Don't be a crutch for insecure technology.

Comment: @isherwood Because that person a) has an old computer with a not-further-updateable old OS that won't allow any newer version of Firefox and b) is the client :-|

Comment: Is he the only customer of the site? What does analytics say about users browsers? What was the agreed upon browsers to support at start of project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself: I added an ID to the `<link>` tag to be able to address it in a simple way and used a simple script wrapped inside a `setTimeout` function to change the value of the `rel` attribute.

Note: Since there is no visible content, there is no visible result in the following snippet window, but the code with the changed attribute can be seen when inspecting the snippet with the browser tools. It also works when the link is inside the `<head>` section, BTW, which is my real-world situation.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
     jQuery('#link_to_sliderstyles1').attr("rel", "stylesheet");
  }, 200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="preload" as="style" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/slider-styles1.css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" id="link_to_sliderstyles1">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the purpose is of this pattern:

```
<link
  rel="preload"
  as="style"
  type="text/css"
  href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/slider-styles1.css"
  onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

It is preloading a stylesheet, then after it preloads it's changing `rel` to `stylesheet` so that it loads for real. Usually `rel="preload"` is for kicking off a download of a resource that isn't loading up front ahead of schedule, prepping it in the cache, whether that's to avoid excessive download waterfalls or to let something that will be loaded dynamically later on will complete sooner.

Since in your case you're wanting it to *always* load the stylesheet on page load, there's no need to do anything with preloading. Just replace with this, and it should be compatible with browsers that don't support preloading:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/slider-styles1.css">
```

If the idea was to use this `preload + onload` as a way to delay loading stylesheet until after page load, a better approach may be to inject the link via some JavaScript:

```
<script>
  var sliderStylesheet = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/slider-styles1.css";
  document.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    link.setAttribute('href', sliderStylesheet);
    document.head.appendChild(link);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for answering! Yes, the purpose is to delay the loading of that second stylesheet. But unfortunately code the you included (i.e. the last code block)  doesn't work (also if I change "header" to "head" in the last line) – the `link` tag isn't added.

Comment: Yep, sorry, should have been `head`. You don't see it added in the DOM inspector? Just want to make sure you're not looking at "View Source" which is only going to show the HTML that is there on first load, not the source code after things are inserted.

Comment: Yes, I am looking at the DOM in the browser tools / inspector, and it's not added.